# Is there any ruby library to generate html form?

Tags: html, ruby, rubygems

Looking for simple html form generator gem.
I have to generate an html form, but its not like ActionView::Form, just generator without any args like:

```
form.create do |f|
  f.text :comment
  f.name :name
end
```

that generates

```
<input type="text" name="comment" />
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

Any gist, or parser/generator or library?

Answer (score 2):

Builder is great.  It works well, and seems to function just about like what something I would write.  The interface is clean and easy.  I used it last week for a similar project.

http://builder.rubyforge.org/

Comment: I looked at it but I couldn't find on how to generate HTML. There is the XML generator only?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the Nokogiri builder. http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/Builder.html

Comment: It does both.  It would be more accurate to call it a *ML generator.  Nokogiri, yeah, I could have mentioned that one too.  I think Builder is simpler for limited HTML requirements.  Glad you've got it.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I didn't realize how poorly documented the builder readme handles their html features.

http://ruby.about.com/od/gems/a/builder.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The [dom](https://rubygems.org/gems/dom) gem that I have developed does exactly what you want. You can generate HTML strings like this:

```
require "dom"
["foo".dom(:span, class: "bold"), "bar"].dom(:div).dom(:body).dom(:html)
# => "<html><body><div><span class=\"bold\">foo</span>bar</div></body></html>"
```